# Слово "неприятнее" выглядит неправильным. Прав ли я?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Иностранец написал:

> В Москве климат неприятнее, чем в Сочи

На мой слух, это звучит неправильно. Можно сказать `хуже` или `менее приятный`, но не `неприятнее`. Прав ли я? Если да, то есть ли какое-то формальное правило, подтверждающее мое мнение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет запрета. В Нацкорпусе русского языка я нашел 225 вхождений слова *неприятнее*, из них 11 с "неприятнее, чем". Примеры:

> Но сегодня было и еще… сегодня было неприятнее, чем всегда, и Алексей не мог понять почему. [Андрей Битов. Сад (1960-1963)]
>
> Видите, я допускаю, что моя болтливость вам может быть еще неприятнее, чем моя смерть. [В. В. Набоков. Solus Rex (1940-1942)]

Comment: Спасибо. Но вы согласны, что в таком контексте, как я привел, это несколько режет слух? Или все-таки звучит нормально, и это просто мне кажется?

Comment: Не режет слух в таком варианте: "Первое неприятно, а второе еще неприятнее, чем первое". А о Вашем примере трудно  судить вне контекста.

Comment: Да, вы правы, так вполне нормально звучит. А в моем примере больше никакого контекста нет, дальше "зимой тут холодно, но но я люблю холод" и рассуждения о плюсах жизни в Москве.

Comment: Если всем известно, что в Сочи  климат неприятный, тогда сойдет. Но ведь не все с этим согласны! А он сразу сравнивает, где  неприятнее. Это стилистически неверно.

Comment: Здесь проблема не в слове "неприятно", другое слово на том же месте вызывает такое же несогласие, например: "Москве ужаснее, чем Сочи". А кто сказал, что Сочи ужасны?

Comment: Спасибо. Я с вами согласен, и мои ощущения прояснились.

Answer (score 1):

**В Москве климат неприятнее, чем в Сочи.**

Мне тоже кажется, что предложение звучит не совсем корректно. Сравнить: **В Москве климат еще неприятнее, чем в Сочи.** (Так уже лучше).

Дело в том, что на слух (при наличии частицы НЕ) мы не различаем, утверждение у нас это или отрицание, поэтому предложение вполне можно понять следующим образом: **В Москве климат не приятнее, чем в Сочи.**

Такая двойственность не очень корректна, утвердительный смысл "неприятнее" желательно как-то **подчеркнуть.** Кстати, **в приведенных примерах** (из предыдущего ответа) структура предложения позволяет считать эту форму утвердительной.

Comment: Вот будет смешно, если выяснится, что иностранец хотел сказать именно это: "не приятнее". В Сочи, дескать, тепло и приятно, а в Москве тоже приятно, но не приятнее, чем в Сочи, потому что   зимой холодно.